# Multiply rows by column value

Tags: sql, postgresql, nested-loops, plpgsql

I need to transform data from my source-table into a destination-table.

The source table has 'content'-columns and 'multiplier'-columns. Based on the multiplier(X), the content of the source should be written X-times into the destination.

eg: if multilpier is '0', nothing will be written, if '1', content is written one time into destination table. Two times, if the multiplier is '2', and so on. I've never done functions in Postgres before.

My approach: a nested for-while-loop: for each row, while 'counter' is smaller than 'multiplier', insert content from source-table into destination table.

Example data:

```
--create source table
create table public.source_tbl(
id serial, 
multiplier int, 
content varchar,
primary key (id)
);
--create destination table
create table public.dest_tbl(
id serial, 
multiplier int, 
content varchar,
primary key (id)
);
--some content
insert into public.source_tbl(multiplier,content)
values(1,'foo'),(1,'bar'),(1,'random'),(2, 'content'),(3,'My'),(4,'creativity'),(3,'is'),(2,'very'),(6,'limited'),(7,'!!!'), (0, 'nothing should be written');
```

And thats the code I came up with:

```
do
$$
declare f record;
begin 
    for f in    select id, multiplier, content
                from public.source_tbl;
    loop
        do
        $$
        declare counter integer counter:=0;
        begin
            while counter < f.multiplier
            loop
                insert into public.dest_tbl(multiplier,content)
                select f.multiplier, f.content;
                counter := counter +1;
            end loop;
        end;
    end loop;
end;
$$
```

Needless to say that it does not work, I get an syntax-error with the second 'declare'. So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot declare a variable in the middle of a `plpgsql` code. It is also not necessary to create another anonymous code block for the second loop. Try this:

```
do
$$ 
declare 
 f record;
 counter integer :=0;
begin 
    for f in select id, multiplier, content from public.source_tbl  loop
      while counter < f.multiplier loop
         insert into public.dest_tbl(multiplier,content)
         select f.multiplier, f.content;
         counter := counter +1;
       end loop;   
       counter := 0;
    end loop;
end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=f874af5704beafef50df0ac9d745fe2a)

Comment: The counter in your example is not resetting though. But I managed to squeeze in a 'counter := 0' in between the two 'end loop' lines.  Now, it works perfectly fine.  If I had more than one 'multiplier'-columns (which I have, of course), is there any chance to iterate this code over multiple columns in an easy way? Oherwise I would simply perform this task on multiple columns manually...

Comment: @JeanLucBizarre if you mean multiple `multiplier` columns I guess you'll need an inner loop for each one of them :-|

Comment: inner loop sounds nasty! but yes, I have multiple(around 20) columns, each indicating the presence (and count) of a specific type of tube in the ground (my 'content' is mostly a geometry). For every kind (and quantity)of tube that is present in that area, I have to duplicate this geometry X-times and add the referring tube-type-code into the destination table. The type-code is not part of the source-table. Judging by your smiley concerning inner loops and my SQL-skills, I guess I should rather copy+adjust the code into a textfile and run in sequentially.

Answer (score 2):

Jim answered immediate question about the syntax error. However, you don't need a function or PL/pgSQL for this. The same can be achieved by using the built-in function `generate_series()`

```
insert into dest_tbl (multiplier, content)
select st.multiplier, st.content
from source_tbl st
  cross join generate_series(1, st.multiplier);
```

Comment: Well, that is another very handy function I've never heard before now. And it gets the job perfectly done. Honestly, at the moment I don't know what this function is actually doing, but I will read into this. Thank you for broaden my mind :-)

Comment: @JeanLucBizarre: it does what the name implies: it generates a series of rows based on a start and end value